# Embedded Path inside a PathParam

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

The API I want to build would include resources like this:

```
@GET
@Path("document/{embedded_path"})
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getDocument(@PathParam("embedded_path") String path){ ... }
```

So that it could be accessed like this:

```
http://example.com/document/relative/path/to/document.txt
```

Nothing I've read so far explicitly forbids or allows resource parameters with the '/' character in them. Is it possible to handle it this way? (The client will likely be javascript, if that matters)

Comment: Have you tried using @Path("document/{embedded_path: *}")

Answer (score 2):

That is possible with wildcards.

```
@Path("/document/{embedded_path:.*}")
```

[Embedded template parameters are allowed and are of the form](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html#value%28%29):

```
param = "{" *WSP name *WSP [ ":" *WSP regex *WSP ] "}"
name = (ALPHA / DIGIT / "_")*(ALPHA / DIGIT / "." / "_" / "-" ) ; \w[\w\.-]*
regex = *( nonbrace / "{" *nonbrace "}" ) ; where nonbrace is any char other than "{" and "}"
```